# Using SSE 4.2 crc32 algorithm in c# ? Is it possible?

Tags: c#, cryptography, sse, crc32

I have to calculate crc32 on a lot of files, and also huge files (several GB). I tried several algo found on the web like [Damieng](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net) or [this one](http://tomkaminski.com/crc32-hashalgorithm-c-net), and it works, but it is slow (more than 1 min).
I found [this benchmark](http://www.strchr.com/crc32_popcnt?allcomments=1) on various crc32 algo and found that sse 4.2 have hardware accelerated crc32 method.

I didn't find anywhere c# code sample to use SSE crc32 code.

1 - Is it possible ?

2 - How can I detect if the current cpu is SSE4.2-enabled ? (to switch the crc32 method)

(please code sample if possible)

Comment: Have you profiled your code? I seriously doubt your problem is due to a slow CRC algorithm, more likely to be the I/O overhead of reading several GB of data.

Comment: @James Indeed, either that or you can utilise `unsafe` code areas with pointer optimisations to get some benefit - though this is just wild conjecture :-)

Comment: Calculating the CRC32 of a several-GB file needs reading the whole file ... and processing it sequentially. Try to measure how long simply reading the whole file (and adding the bytes or 32-bit blocks, to avoid that your system optimizes the reading away) takes, compare this with your CRC32 calculation.

Comment: The cryptography tag along with CRC32 is downright frightening, I really hope it's an error (in which case please remove the tag), otherwise you have a whole lot more problem than a slow calculation.

Comment: @Bruno You're right, but the crc32 algorithm fits perfectly in the .net System.Security.Cryptography pattern. That's why I added the tag. Anyway, if it annoys someone else, I could remove it. I use it for files identification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays we've been spoiled with the `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86` namespace available in .NET Core 3.0. Here's the full implementation of the CRC32-C algorithm using SSE 4.2:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

/// <summary>
/// The hardware implementation of the CRC32-C polynomial 
/// implemented on Intel CPUs supporting SSE4.2.
/// </summary>
public class Crc32HardwareAlgorithm : HashAlgorithm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// the current CRC value, bit-flipped
    /// </summary>
    private uint _crc;

    /// <summary>
    /// We can further optimize the algorithm when X64 is available.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _x64Available;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Crc32HardwareAlgorithm()
    {
        if (!Sse42.IsSupported)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("SSE4.2 is not supported");
        }

        _x64Available = Sse42.X64.IsSupported;

        // The size, in bits, of the computed hash code.
        this.HashSizeValue = 32;
        this.Reset();
    }

    /// <summary>When overridden in a derived class, routes data written to the object into the hash algorithm for computing the hash.</summary>
    /// <param name="array">The input to compute the hash code for.</param>
    /// <param name="ibStart">The offset into the byte array from which to begin using data.</param>
    /// <param name="cbSize">The number of bytes in the byte array to use as data.</param>
    protected override void HashCore(byte[] array, int ibStart, int cbSize)
    {
        if (_x64Available)
        {
            while (cbSize >= 8)
            {
                _crc = (uint)Sse42.X64.Crc32(_crc, BitConverter.ToUInt64(array, ibStart));
                ibStart += 8;
                cbSize -= 8;
            }
        }

        while (cbSize > 0)
        {
            _crc = Sse42.Crc32(_crc, array[ibStart]);
            ibStart++;
            cbSize--;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>When overridden in a derived class, finalizes the hash computation after the last data is processed by the cryptographic stream object.</summary>
    /// <returns>The computed hash code.</returns>
    protected override byte[] HashFinal()
    {
        uint outputCrcValue = ~_crc;

        return BitConverter.GetBytes(outputCrcValue);
    }

    /// <summary>Initializes an implementation of the <see cref="T:System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm"></see> class.</summary>
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        this.Reset();
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        _crc = uint.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this only read the array 1 byte at a time?  The [x86 CRC32 instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/crc32) is available with 1,2,4, or 8 byte source size.  In C++, `_mm_crc32_u64`.  This would go 8x faster than using it one byte at a time; the latency is fixed at 3 cycles regardless of input size.  (32-bit mode can only do up to 4 bytes at a time)

Comment: You're right. I just updated the answer with the X64 version of it. It's slightly faster now.

Comment: Only "slightly"?  Are you testing on tiny inputs?  Or is your benchmark dominated by warm-up time?  Or does that not compile efficiently for some reason?  For medium or larger buffers (like 1kiB should be plenty to hide startup / cleanup overhead), that should be 8x faster.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just realized something funny. With 1GB of data and on my I7 CPU,  with the polynomial tables I get the hash in 1080ms, X32 SSE in 2660ms and X64 SSE in 353ms. And the results are consistent. You'd think the hardware version is always faster :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure in asm the CRC32 instruction 8 bytes at a time is the fastest possible way, certainly on Intel CPUs.  If that's not the case for your C# code then it didn't compile efficiently.  Would it help to use a local tmp var instead of the `_crc` class member inside the loop to make sure it can be optimized into a register?  Are you sure you're using Release mode and doing enough of a warm-up run?

Comment: Wait, when you say "X32 SSE", do you mean running this exact SSE4.2 code in 32-bit mode?  It will have to emulate `Sse42.X64.Crc32(..., ..., UInt64)` because like I said, 32-bit only has direct HW support for chunks up to 32-bit.  64-bit operand-size isn't available in 32-bit mode.  I'm surprised it can run at all.  Your results show a good speedup for 64-bit mode.  In absolute terms, 8-byte at a time `crc32 rax, [rdi]` has 3 cycle latency, so your throughput should be 8 bytes per 3 clock cycles.  Testing repeated passes over the same 8k buffer would avoid cache miss bottlenecks, BTW.

Comment: @PeterCordes I ran the tests in Release mode, 64 bit. When I wrote X32 I meant the uint variant, which appears to be slower than the software version with lookup tables. I double checked my results, made sure the tests were warmed up, running on the same byte array and multiple times in the same go. I also tried with streams, because this code will run against files at the end of the day, and the results weren't far behind. Internally the HashAlgorithm class  uses a 4KB buffer for streams. You're free to run your own tests and share your results.

Comment: I don't have Windows or .NET installed.  All I can tell you is what's efficient in asm.  If a 32-bit operand-size version of this loop wasn't twice the time of 64-bit, then your compiler did a terrible job.  IDK why, but that's obviously the case.  It's certainly plausible, though.  This depends on `BitConverter.ToUInt64` or `32` basically optimizing into a simple load or memory source operand for a `crc32` instruction.  If it doesn't then you have a problem.

Comment: The reason why 32-bit is so much slower is because if x64 is not available, it runs the `while (cbSize > 0)` portion, which means the entire CRC is calculated 1 byte at a time. To fix this, add the following just before `while (cbSize > 0)` (sorry, can't do multiple lines): `while (cbSize >= 4) 
{
 _crc = Sse42.Crc32(_crc, BitConverter.ToUInt32(array, ibStart));
 ibStart += 4;
 cbSize -= 4;
}`

Comment: That said, in my testing, I found that even using the x64 Intrinsics method is only around 25% faster than using a pure C# slice-by-16 algorithm. My fix only increases x86 mode to around 50% slower than the software algorithm. What did make a huge difference was calling the methods in these C++ DLLs, which are around 7.5x faster than the x64 Intrinsics method: https://crc32c.machinezoo.com/#cpp

Answer (score 1):

I believe Mono allows access to CPU instructions via the Mono.Simd namespace:

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-03.html

Stackoverflow related question:

[Using SSE in c# is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415375/using-sse-in-c-is-it-possible)

The Mono code is open source.  It looks like you can't just add this to a .NET project to get the benefit though as it appears to need the Mono runtime:

[Calling mono c# code from Microsoft .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476486/calling-mono-c-code-from-microsoft-net)

That said, it will work, but it will be software emulated.